# Problem with multiple labels in Highchart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts

Im trying to design a chart similar to this:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81H6o.png)

Im tried to use Highchart Horizontal bar chart, But i cant able to add two labels to it. Is there any options available in highchart to do it.

Or this should be done with `d3.js` but i think it needs more development then highcahrt.

Any help or advice will be helpful.

Highchart sample im referring:http://jsfiddle.net/j0rhypfq/
D3.js sample im referring:  https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_horizontal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the grouped-categories plugin for Highcharts:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [{
        name: "enero",
        categories: ["Gasto Real", "Presupusto USD"]
    }, {
        name: "febrero",
        categories: ["Gasto Real", "Presupusto USD"]
    }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zfcg5xhs/

**Docs:** http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

Comment: Wow!! super thanks. So we don't have such option in Highcharts.. and thanks for the group-category js work too.